# External output paths for Typescript

Tags: json, typescript, output, tsc, tsconfig

My Project structure is as follows:

```
Root
|
+- /build
|  |
|  +- /server
|  |
|  +- /app
|
+- /source
   |
   +- /server
   |  |
   |  +-tsconfig.json
   |  |
   |  +-(typescript files)
   |
   +- /app
      |
      +- tsconfig.json
      |
      +- (typescript files)
```

I am trying to use different tsconfig.json files by using:

```
tsc -p <path>
```

The reason for that are different output targets. When I specify outdir inside the tsconfig.json file inside the /server folder as

```
    "outDir": "./../build/server"
```

it creates folders inside source named build/server

Is there a way of navigating further back than the specified project root?